Working with 4D data in Python with entries having variable sizes (are not homogeneous)
I am a civil engineer and I need to collect results from a finite element model and work with data having four dimensions.

Load combinations in the building model (can range from 3 to 60 or so)
The frames in the building (can range can from a couple to hundreds depending on the size of the model/building).
The types of force (size=3), will be bending moment, shear force and axial force.
The station value (the model measures forces at multiple points on the frames (can range from 2 to 100).

Creating a four dimensional array should be straightforward, but the problem is that numpy arrays are rectangular and the last dimension above (StaVal) can have different size because not all frames will have equal stations, because of different frame mesh sizes. Any help or advice will be very helpful and will appreciate greatly. If there is a better approach than numpy, I would love to know that too. Here is the code I am using:
import numpy as np

#Getting a list of all load combinations
NumberNames=0
MyName1=[]
[NumberNames, MyName1, ret] = SapModel.RespCombo.GetNameList(NumberNames, MyName)


#Function to get names of all frames
NumberNames=0
MyName2=[]
[NumberNames,MyName2,ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.GetNameList(NumberNames, MyName)
print(NumberNames)
print(MyName)
frames = np.array(MyName)

#Getting all forces for all frames for all combinations for all stations (this is where I am stuck)
forces = np.array([NumberNames,len(MyName2),3])
for i in range(len(MyName1)):
    moment[i] = []
    shear[i] = []
    axial[i] = []
    for i in range(len(frames)):
        SapModel.Results.Setup.SetComboSelectedForOutput(Name=MyName2[i],Selected=True)
        NumberResults=0
        ObjectElm = 0
        Obj=[]
        ObjSta=[]
        Elm=[]
        ElmSta=[]
        LoadCase=[]
        StepType=[]
        StepNum=[]
        P=[]
        V2=[]
        V3=[]
        T=[]
        M2=[]
        M3=[]
        [NumberResults, Obj, ObjSta, Elm, ElmSta, LoadCase, StepType, StepNum, P, V2, V3, T, M2, M3,ret]=SapModel.Results.FrameForce(MyName2[i], ObjectElm, NumberResults, Obj, ObjSta, Elm, ElmSta, MyName, StepType, StepNum, P, V2, V3, T, M2, M3)
        moment[i].append(np.array(M3))
        shear[i].append(np.array(V2))
        axial[i].append(np.array(P))



It depends on what you want to do with the collected data. An approach can be a pandas dataframes or an SQL-database with a separate table for the fourth dimension.

I will be doing multiple operations on the data; for example, I will be creating plots of the three forces for each frame, get the maximum force for a particular frame and then see if the frame is strong enough to take that load, get the bending moment, shear and axial force at a particular station of a frame and check for combined loading equations. Maybe at a later stage I will add a fifth dimension for the length of the frame or a sixth dimension for area of the frame. Do you suggest pandas or SQL over the other?

If there is enough main memory to hold all the data at once, pandas is the better approach. It allows multi-level indexes to e. g. group station values of a particular frame and more advanced math than the usual data base.

@user19077881 The problem is that the last dimension, StationValue, has variable length for each frame. I do not know how I can handle that in numpy.

@MichaelButscher Thank you! I believe there should be enough main memory. Okay, I will try to use Pandas for this. Any ideas for the case when the size of the last dimension is variable?

Pandas multi-index is structurally no different than a N-dimension Numpy array other than named labels can be used in Pandas rather than numerical indices. Indeed Pandas is based on Numpy arrays 'under the hood'.

@user19077881 Thank you for the info - with that knowledge, do you know of a suitable way to dimension an array (be it in pandas or numpy) when the size of one of the dimension is variable? I can try to take the maximum size of that dimension (StationVal) from all frames and make that as the size (putting zero's for smaller frames) - but I do not know how to implement that.

@user19077881 Except that the number of rows for different labels in a level of the index don't have to be equal.

Since you have non-homogeneous sizes, use a loop to access the "frames", numpy is most likely a bad choice. You probably should use a tidy pandas dataframe. Or even a pure python container (e.g. a dictionary) with an array for each minimal unit on which you'll perform your computation.

i agree with @mozway. if the data is not homogeneous, then an array is suboptimal. A dictionary is more suitable in this instance. one can have arrays (of different lengths) inside a dictionary.

You might probably also want to adjust the title of your question; it appears a bit misleading to me: the problem, as you already noted, is not that your data is 4D, but that your entries have variable sizes (are not homogeneous, as mozway called it).

In order for anyone to assist you in making a DataFrame, you should probably share the shape of the various variables that you get out of your function.  As of right now it's pretty difficult to parse how the various arrays fit together.  Best guess is that the column names would be the forces (since they are constant size and what you'll want to compare), and the loading combinations, frames, and station values would be a MultiIndex index variable.

@simon Thanks - I changed the title of the question.

@D.L and mozway, thank you - I will try to use dictionary too to see how that fits.

@DanielF For my current case, I have 20 load combinations, I have 8 frames (4 columns, 4 beams), variable number of stations on each frame (8 for columns and 12 for beams), and 3 values at each station (bending moment, shear and axial force). Thank you - does that help?
